# json parameter to request on Windows 8 (RT)

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime

### I'm looking for solution to send request with `JSON` like parameter to server.

I use this code,

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var tempByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my valid json");
var stream = new MemoryStream(tempByteArray);
var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Constants.LocalServer);
request.Content = streamContent;
request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

But in response I get:

```
{
    StatusCode: 501,
    ReasonPhrase: 'NotImplemented',
    Version: 1.0,
    Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
    Headers: {
        X-Squid-Error: ERR_UNSUP_REQ0X-Cache: MISSfromproxy3.itos.orgX-Cache-Lookup: NONEfromproxy3.companyname.org: portProxy-Connection: closeDate: Thu,
        18Apr201309: 17: 53GMTServer: squid/2.6.STABLE21Via: 1.0proxy3.companyname.org: port(squid/2.6.STABLE21)Content-Length: 1099Content-Type: text/htmlExpires: Thu,
        18Apr201309: 17: 53GMT
    }
}
```

May be have another way to sent request with json parameter on Win8?

### UPDATE I found solution:

```
public static async Task<string> LoadData(string json, string serverUrl)  
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(Constants.LocalServer));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (var requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
        writer.Write(json);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    using (var resp = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            return  = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

It's work great, but must exists more simple way(i hope). And I'll **try** to find it.

Comment: That looks like an error on the server side, not the client side. Are you sure that the request that you are building is what the server expects?

Comment: yes, i'm sure. use it from ios version of app.

Comment: Did you check with Fiddler that the request that you *think* you are sending is the request that you are *actually* sending? It may be that the request has extra or missing headers that are default on iOS, but not for the `HttpClient`, for example.

Comment: @madd0, I updated my question, and search continues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that moment this solution is most useful.

```
public static async Task<string> LoadData(string json, string serverUrl)  
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(Constants.LocalServer));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (var requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
        writer.Write(json);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    using (var resp = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            return  = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I post data using your two code snippets, I see some differences in the requests.

Here is the raw post for the first code sample (that you say does not work):

```
POST http://testing.foo.com/api/Values HTTP/1.1
Host: testing.foo.com
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 75

{
id:"1",
title:"title text",
post:"post text",
isDeleted:"False"
}
```

This is the raw post for the code in your update (code that you say works):

```
POST http://testing.foo.com/api/Values HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: testing.foo.com
Content-Length: 75
Expect: 100-continue

{
id:"2",
title:"title text",
post:"post text",
isDeleted:"False"
}
```

The differences in the two requests are as follows:

1. In the first request, the content type is never set.
2. In the first request, the content is UTF8 encoded.

To fix your non-working code, I would suggest you try one or both of the following:

1. Set the content type to application/json
2. Not UTF8 encode the request

Comment: Sorry, you answer wasn't helpful for me, and I accepted my own. But only you spent own time to help me and you should get a bounty.